# Bool query over child and parent fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Just started to play with Elasticsearch. 
I am trying to do a search on some child documents by querying on both child and parent fields.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "has_child": {
                        "type": "mychildtype",
                        "query": {
                            "match": {
                                "child_field": "value1"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "parent_field": "value2"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "fields": [
        "_type",
        "_id",
        "parent_field1",
        "parent_field2"
    ]
}
```

I get the error:

```
{
  "error" : "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed; shardFailures {[PfjRtoQKRZeIxkokAo_vmA][*INDEX_NAME*][0]: SearchParseException[[*INDEX_NAME*][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [*ESCAPED QUERY*]; nested: QueryParsingException[[*INDEX_NAME*] [_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }]",
  "status" : 400
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I got it. I was missing a "match":{  } around my parent field criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was missing a "match":{ } around my parent field criteria.

Comment: Can you please write down your final query in your answer?